# How to simulate a click of an element with randomly generated ID?

Tags: javascript, bots, javascript-objects

So I'm trying to create a bot for a web based game I play, but encountering a major issue. In order to perform certain actions, you need to select Okay, or Yes to go through with them. [More detail in below image.] But the element ID is randomly generated, which makes it difficult to latch onto the correct element to click.

```
    document.getElementById('elementID').click();
```

Is what I was trying to use early [element ID filled in oc] but as it's random I'm not able to use that to find the element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Evelyn

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FONQi.png)

Comment: So you want to create a bot to cheat a game.... well as for that **pop-up** message you will need something in place to detect it before you can input/give it dynamic/false data. What do you have so far?

Comment: You can select the element by class too, like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("confirm_okay");` and then call the **click** on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element has a non-changing class you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

If it doesn't then you will have to use `document.getElementsByTagName("<insert tag name of button>")`. Then loop through the list and check the innerhtml value to see if it is the correct button.

Example:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button")

for (buttonNumber in buttons) {

button = buttons[buttonNumber]

if (button.innerHTML == "Okay") {

button.click()

}

}
```